# Hazelcast MBean is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx, hazelcast

I migrated an app to Spring Boot including migration from XML to Java config. The app uses Hazelcast and it does work. However, I can't see Hazelcast MBean in JConsole anymore. The only thing I've managed to find regarding enabling JMX is the property

```
properties.put("hazelcast.jmx", true);
```

But that doesn't help. This is the config before the migration:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hzInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="gsynth" password="gsynth"/>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.jmx">true</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.version.check.enabled">false</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.icmp.enabled">true</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled">true</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.max.operation.timeout">60000</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.restart.on.max.idle">true</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                <hz:tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <hz:members>${members.list}</hz:members>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
<hz:map id="serviceHash" instance-ref="hzInstance" name="service-hash"/>
<hz:map id="persisterHash" instance-ref="hzInstance" name="persister-hash"/>
```

And now it looks like this:

```
public class HazelcastConfig
{

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hzInstance(Config hzConfig)
    {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hzConfig(@Value("${members.list}") String membersList)
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
        properties.put("hazelcast.jmx", true);
        properties.put("hazelcast.version.check.enabled", false);
        properties.put("hazelcast.icmp.enabled", true);
        properties.put("hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled", true);
        properties.put("hazelcast.max.operation.timeout", 60000);
        properties.put("hazelcast.restart.on.max.idle", true);

        return new Config().setGroupConfig(new GroupConfig().setName("gsynth").setPassword("gsynth")).setProperties(
                properties).setNetworkConfig(
                new NetworkConfig().setPort(5701).setPortAutoIncrement(false).setJoin(
                        new JoinConfig().setMulticastConfig(new MulticastConfig().setEnabled(false)).setTcpIpConfig(
                                new TcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).addMember(membersList))));
    }

    @Bean
    public IMap serviceHash(HazelcastInstance hzInstance)
    {
        return hzInstance.getMap("service-hash");
    }

    @Bean
    public IMap persisterHash(HazelcastInstance hzInstance)
    {
        return hzInstance.getMap("persister-hash");
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found the issue: the thing is that I was using Properties like this:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
    properties.put("hazelcast.jmx", true);
    ...
```

So `true` was set as boolean. Internally Hazelcast in its source code was getting null here in the file `GroupProperties.java` on the 752th line:

```
String configValue = (config != null) ? config.getProperty(name) : null;
```

If you dig deeper you will see that `config.getProperty(name)` will return null because of this fancy thing on the 969th line of the `Properties.java` file (as in the JDK 1.8.0_102):

```
Object oval = super.get(key);
String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
```

`oval` in this case corresponded to the "hazelcast.jmx" key thus being `true` but as **BOOLEAN** not **String** as required.

The fix is straightforward:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");
properties.put("hazelcast.jmx", "true");
...
```

Just make all non-string values string.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please ensure you have enabled JMX Agent by setting the system properties as below

> ```
>     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
>     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=_portNo\_ (to specify JMX port, the default is 1099) (optional)
>     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
> ```

Then you try a simpler setup as below to ensure if it works , and if it does then check the construction of the config in your program.

```
Config config = new Config();
config.setProperty("hazelcast.jmx", "true");
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Comment: this is the way I'm doing it. I can verify other JMX beans exist via JConsole. But I don't see one from Hazelcast

Comment: which version of hazelcast are you using?

Comment: the version is 3.5